# How to replicate jQuery slideUp()/slideDown() with Angular animation?

Tags: jquery, angular, animation

I want to basically add a smooth animation (similar to jQuery's slideUp/slideDown methods) to an element with the *ngIf directive. So far, I've tried this:

```
trigger('slideUpDown', [
  transition('void => *', [
    style({height: 0, margin: 0, padding: 0}),
    animate(1500, style({height: '*', margin: '*', padding: '*'}))
  ]),
  transition('* => void', [
    style({height: '*', margin: '*', padding: '*'}),
    animate(1500, style({height: 0, margin: 0, padding: 0}))
  ])
])
```

Template:

```
<div>
    <label (click)="showEmailForm = !showEmailForm"><strong>Mail</strong></label>
</div>
<div [@slideUpDown] *ngIf="showEmailForm">
    <campaign-email-channel-form  [channel]="channels?.mail" [isSaving]="isSavingEmailChannel" (save)="onSaveEmailChannel($event)"></campaign-email-channel-form>
</div>
```

This is not working correctly. What happens is that the div on which the animation is set seems to be animated correctly, but its content (the form component) becomes immediately visible in its entirety.

I also tried setting the animation and *ngIf on the component itself, but that way, the animation doesn't even do anything, even though through using the animation callbacks I was able to confirm they were being triggered.

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` as a style to the containing div

Comment: Yep, that fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animations are all set up correctly, it's just that the div that contains the `<campaign>` element does not hide any overflow. Once `*ngIf` becomes `true`, the element is inserted in the DOM. The `<div>` animates, but since it doesn't hide the overflowing element it gets displayed immediately. A couple of possible solutions would be:

- Use `<campaign-email-channel-form *ngIf="showEmailForm" [@slideUpDown]>`
- Add `overflow: hidden` as a style to the containing div -- at least while it is animating.

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried the first solution and like I said, the animation didn't even work that way, it only worked when I added it on an outer element. overflow: hidden fixed it though.